# How to set a default Tab in SwiftUIs TabView?

Tags: swift, swiftui, tabview

I have a `TabView` in `SwiftUI` and want the second tab to be the default, when starting the app.

I haven't found any documentation to provide this behavior, but it should be possible. Most of the apps have the mid tab as their default tab.

```swift
TabView {
    QuestionView()
        .tabItem {
            Image(systemName: "questionmark")
            Text("Questions")
        }
    DataView()
        .tabItem {
            Image(systemName: "chart.bar.fill")
            Text("Data")
        }
    Text("Empty Tab right now")
        .tabItem {
            Image(systemName: "bolt.horizontal.fill")
            Text("Trend")
        }
}
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

```
@State private var selection = 3

TabView(selection:$selection) {
     QuestionView()
          .tabItem {
              Image(systemName: "questionmark")
              Text("Questions")
          }
          .tag(1)
     DataView()
          .tabItem {
              Image(systemName: "chart.bar.fill")
              Text("Data")
          }
          .tag(2)
     Text("Empty Tab right now")
          .tabItem {
              Image(systemName: "bolt.horizontal.fill")
              Text("Trend")
          }
          .tag(3)
}
```

In this case I set default selected the third `Tab`. Change `selection` to the desired `Tab`.

Comment: Start tag number from 0 if you don't want to change `selection` manually.

Comment: Why does this answer not work and the answer adding .tag(1) does work?

Answer (score 9):

Define a `State` with the default value and bind it to `TabView`:

```
@State var selection = 1
,,,

    TabView(selection: $selection) 

,,,
```

Then assign a `tag` to each `tabItem`:

```
,,,
    .tabItem {
        Image(systemName: "bolt.horizontal.fill")
        Text("Trend")
    }.tag(1)
,,,
```

Now you can use them together, `selection` === `tag`

Comment: Preferred this answer for specifying the use of `tag` on each `tabItem`

Answer (score 4):

We can use `enum` with specific `View` name cases for `tag` rather than using `Int`s.

```
func tag<V>(_ tag: V) -> some View where V : Hashable
```

Please note that `tag` has to be confirmed to Hashable protocol so you can the enum cases like below.

```
enum Tab: String, CaseIterable, Identifiable {
    case question
    case data
    case empty

    var id: Self { self }
}

@State private var tab = Tab.data

TabView(selection: $tab) {
     QuestionView()
          .tabItem {
              Image(systemName: "questionmark")
              Text("Questions")
          }
          .tag(Tab.question)
     DataView()
          .tabItem {
              Image(systemName: "chart.bar.fill")
              Text("Data")
          }
          .tag(Tab.data)
     Text("Empty Tab right now")
          .tabItem {
              Image(systemName: "bolt.horizontal.fill")
              Text("Trend")
          }
          .tag(Tab.empty)
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Much cleaner than using ints. Though you don't necessarily need `String, CaseIterable, Identifiable`, just `Hashable` is enough.